# Which is the fastest method to reshape a vector to a matrix of overlapping windows in C++ using Eigen library?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, eigen, overlap

Let's suppose you have a vector of N elements and you want to create a n by m matrix made of stacked overlapping windows sliced from the original vector. Which is the fastest way to perform this operation in C++ using Eigen library?

for ex (N = 7, window_length(m) = 3, overlap = 2):

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 -> 0, 1, 2
                       1, 2, 3
                       2, 3, 4
                       3, 4, 5
                       4, 5, 6
```

where m and overlap must be parametric.

Comment: I don't know about Eigen library. But in theory the fastest way would be to **not** make any operation. Just modify the way you are indexing the array. On a custom class, this just means writing a `int operator()(size_t row, size_t column)` method that is aware of the overlapping.

Comment: Hi @prapin, thank you for your comment, I agree with you. However, for various reasons, I actually need a new matrix (for example a MatrixXd Eigen type) built as I mentioned above.

Comment: You could create an Eigen::Map with a outer-stride of 1 (not sure anymore, if this is supposed to work, but it should).

Comment: Hi @chtz thanks! Your suggestion worked to replicate the example I made but I can't figure it out how to generalize the mapping in case of parametric overlap (ex. overlap=1, m=3 or overlap=4, m=7).